# macOS: Create chrome custom shortcut app installer (Site-specific browser)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, big-sur

How do I create a [custom chrome shortcut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site-specific_browser) in MAC OS where:

1. App is **completely separate** from the default chrome install in every way.  Normally you would copy/paste chrome to its own folder and specify a user folder path to accomplish this.
2. Specify **whatever settings I want**.  For example, I want the **address bar and tabs hidden**.  Normally you specify the -app=whatever.com to do that.
3. App gets **custom icon** in the dock.
4. Has a fancy DMG or equivalent installer, like chrome has.  So **users can install it hassle free**.

Comment: This really isn't going to work in the way you imagine. You can't just install an app & keep it separate from any other version of the same app unless you have the source code & can give it a different app signature before compile. Same for settings & icon. After that, the .dmg is the easy bit.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So maybe try compiling my own version of chrome?  https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/mac_build_instructions.md

Comment: That's Chromium, but close enough. I have not the faintest idea how you'd go from there ;) Future questions will likely belong on the 'mothership' - https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: lol.. the 'mothership' thats hilarious!  So lets pretend for a second that I had my .app ready to go with everything.  How do I create my fancy DMG file from the .app?

Comment: See https://github.com/create-dmg/create-dmg or search for [create dmg](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=create+dmg).

Comment: Depending on what you're actually trying to do, you may want to look at Nativefier: https://github.com/nativefier/nativefier

Comment: Also, you could just replace the .app within Chrome's DMG. Convert the image to read write in Disk Utility, make your edits, then convert it read only ("compressed").

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments!  @Wowfunhappy, I think nativefier is probably going to be the right answer.  I tried it already.  Surprisingly, it wasn't painful at all.  It uses chrome 89.  Hopefully theres a way to specify which chrome version you want.  I do see a javascript error.  Disabling javascript source maps fixes that.  When said and done, it creates a 182.8MB file.  We'll see how much that compresses.  I'll report back in two weeks.

Comment: @Graham Miln, I tried create-dmg, from memory:   It either didn't work, or gave me errors.  I'll try it again sometime.  I have found a manual way of doing dmg files:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cal9l-ajWrE

Comment: @JeffLuyet `--electron-version X.X.X` sets the version. Note it's tied to the Electron version, which sometimes trails upstream Chromium. And, it gives you the latest version by default.